# setters/getters in one method

Tags: php, oop, setter, getter

Just an idea:

example (in PHP):
to set name:
$object->name('name');
to get name:
$object->name();

If no argument: the method is used as getter, else as setter. For simple getters/setter. Stupid, whatever, maybe?

edit: to follow up on the answers: I don't really like **get and set** because I prefer to have the interface as explicit as possible. When there are only a few properties it's also overkill IMHO. So I'd like to narrow it down to classes/objects with a couple of explicit getters/setters.

Comment: If you prefer the interface to be as explicit as possible, why are you even considering having one method that does two different things depending on what gets passed to it?

Comment: Good question. I was hoping that the idea would be clear when confronted with it. Not as clear as having setX/getX but sufficient to trade off a little clarity for a less cluttered interface.

Comment: I've tried many different methods, and using a function with the same name as the class property is my favourite. `__get` and `__set` make the calling code nice but the class code a bit ugly. And there is not much difference between `$obj->property` and  `$obj->property()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could do that if it makes sense in your application, otherwise I would just use the standard getters/setters which have already been set up for you. Your function could look something like this:

```
public function name($val = null)
{
  if (is_null($val))
  {
    return $this->name;
  }
  else
  {
    $this->name = $val;
  }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I'd like to point out that this kind of combined getter/setter doesn't allow you to set the property in question to NULL.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is it would be hard to follow. I'd much rather use PHP5's __get and __set so it is more natural to get and set variables, and everyone would know exactly what I am doing. IE:

```
class myClass
{

    function __get($name)
    {
       return $this->array[$name];
    }
    function __set($name, $value)
    {
       $this->array[$name] = $value;
    }
    function print()
    {
       echo $this->array['test'];
    }
}
$obj = new myClass;
$obj->test = "Hi";
echo $obj->test; //echos Hi.
$obj->print(); //echos Hi.
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using the __call() magic method.

```
class Test {
    public function __call($name, array $args) {
        $variable =& $this->$name;
        if(!empty($args)) {
            $variable = $args[0];
        }
        return $variable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally returning the property for sets?

Comment: Its probably for brevity, but could be a nice side effect, especially if you put something in there to restrict what variables could be added.